# how encrypt my Ks: base64[Ku(Ks)] in php / codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, base64, rsa

I have a Ks, which is a symmetric key generated by me. And I have a public key (Ku) that was provided by a client. What I do is: I want to encrypt the symmetric key (Ks) with the public key (Ku) according to the algorithm RSA and Base64-encoded.

```
 base64 [Eku (Ks)]
```

How can I do this in php?, Or using the CodeIgniter framework? I import some library?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this PHP [library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)